# Creating a table with info from another table

Tags: sql, plsql, package

I am trying to create a package that reads the content from two tables (with fields `tablename`, `schema` and the another with `tablename` and `columnname`). I have to use `dbms_output`

However, I am stuck how to declare the `cursors` and how to doing that. I was thinking to do a `For`, but I don't know what to do after.

Do you have any idea how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a package that reads data but a procedure (which may reside in a package) or just an anonymous block. Here is how:

```
begin
  for rec in (select * from a join b using (tablename)) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.schema || '.' || rec.tablename || '.' || rec.columnname);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and if I must create those tables, how can I do it?

Comment: With CREATE TABLE. How else?

Comment: But My question refers to how can I use the for cycle to doing that. I know that I have to use "CREATE TABLE", but how can I do it dinamically? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Hm, sorry, I don't know what you want to do actually. In your request you say you have two tables containing table and column names and you want to show their Content with dbms_output. Now you ask how to create tables. So: What do you have? What do you want?